# How to make Bootstrap rows fill the height of the parent container?

Tags: css, html

The the following example, I would like my rows to fill the total height of the parent container with the following rule:

- A = 2/6 of the height
- B = 1/6 of the height
- C = 3/6 of the height

Here the code I wrote:

```
<div class="container border border-warning" style="height: 400px">
  <div id="a" class="row row-4 bg-primary">A</div>
  <div id="b" class="row row-2 bg-secondary">B</div>
  <div id="c" class="row row-3 bg-info">C</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjoKpG

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these CSS rules

```
.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
.container > #a{
    flex:0.33 1;
}
.container > #b{
    flex:0.17 1;
}
.container > #c{
    flex:0.5 1;
}
```

Comment: Is this Bootstrap?

Comment: These are 4 CSS' rules in "Bootstrap's like syntax" (using flex positioning). This is not compatible with IE7/IE8 but it is like Bootstrap is doing it

Answer (score 1):

Use height percents:

```
#a { height: 33%}
#b { height: 17%}
#c { height: 50%}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejXKQg